# Xamarin Form: No Ping Reply from Ping Class

Tags: networking, xamarin, ping, connectivity

I am trying to use Ping class to send a ping to a iP address to a remote device.

```
            var ping = new Ping();
            var pingReply = ping.Send(LauncherClient.Instance.DeviceInfo.Ip, 5000);

            if (pingReply.Status != IPStatus.TimedOut) {
                LauncherClient.Instance.Disconnect(null);
            }
```

Problem is the application stops at the Send method and never receive or timeout back so the if statement never reached.

Does the Ping class good to use to check the connectivity between two devices.

Comment: - what platform are you targeting that is having issues 
 - did you add the require networking permissions if needed
 - surround your action in a try catch bracket to see your error
 - I would also like to mention an alternate route and use this plugin since your using forms and the Ping class is not suppport in PCL 
    https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/ConnectivityPlugin

Comment: I am targeting android and iOS. I actually using thrift to call to the server.  It have the timeout property i can set and have set to 5000ms but it doesn't quit after 5000ms even though at some point it will but not the time i have set